# How to describe these combinatorial sets in general and prove their cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, integers

The sets I am looking at are defined as follows: for $k=1$ the set is defined as:

$\Sigma_1:=\Big\{ \frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{3}\Big\}$

whereas for $k=2$ we have

$\Sigma_{2}:=\Big\{ \frac{1}{1},\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{1}{7} \Big\}$

and for $k=3$ we have

$\Sigma_{3}:= \Big\{ \frac{1}{1},\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{1},\frac{5}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{1}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{5}{7},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{11} \Big\}$

I struggle finding a general rule for this. However, I am quite sure that the cardinality of each $\Sigma_{k}$ is equal to three times the triangular number minus one i.e.

$\frac{3k(k+1)}{2}-1$

since from above we may observe that

$|\Sigma_1| = 2$, $|\Sigma_2|=8$, $|\Sigma_3|=17$.

Edit: $\Sigma_4$ would be defined as

$\Sigma_4 := \Big\{ \frac{1}{1},\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{1},\frac{4}{1},\frac{5}{1},\frac{7}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{7}{5},\frac{1}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{5}{7},\frac{1}{9},\frac{5}{9},\frac{7}{9},\frac{1}{11},\frac{3}{11},\frac{1}{13},\frac{1}{15} \Big\}$

Is there any way of deriving a general formula for each $\Sigma_k$ and proving this cardinality? Notice that in each set $\Sigma_k$ for each $\frac{n}{m}$ you want to have $\text{gcd}(n,m)=1$.

Each set corresponds to positive slopes found in $1$, $2$ and $3$ layered hexagons divided by $\sqrt{3}$. For instance, the first set describes positive slopes in a single regular hexagon divided by $\sqrt{3}$, in particular, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{1}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \rightarrow \frac{1}{3}$. The set $\Sigma_3$ would correspond to the positive slopes found in the given image minus $0$ and $\infty$. For example, the points 13 and 32 in the given image would define the slope $\sqrt{3}$ which corresponds to $\frac{1}{1}$ and 20 and 24 define the slope $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}$ which corresponds to $\frac{1}{5}$.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how $\Sigma_k$ is defined? Or is the task to guess how the pattern continues from looking at these examples?

Comment: In general $\Sigma_k$ would be defined as $\frac{a}{b}$ from $\{\frac{a}{b}\cdot \sqrt{3}\}$ which as a set would define all the slopes found in layered regular hexagons on a triangle grid. I do not know how to provide more of an accurate formula.

Comment: I don't quite follow, but that seems like important information to include in your question. Does the definition of $\Sigma_k$ involve $k$?

Comment: $\Sigma_k$ stands for the nonnegative slopes (divided by $\sqrt{3}$) minus $0$ and $\infty$ found in $k$ layered hexagons. I edited the question, and in the given image this is $k=3$.

Comment: Also, the slopes are simply defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$ between each couple of points in the drawing.

Comment: I had to flip the image to make the slopes correspond properly. The sets $\Sigma_k$ corresponds to $k$ layered regular hexagons that are each placed on their edge.

Comment: I don't see how $13$ and $32$ give $\sqrt3$ in this image. I get $-3\sqrt3$, and it is definitely a negative slope. (I agree that $20$ and $24$ give $\frac15\sqrt3$.)